# Strategy Design pattern vs State Design pattern

Tags: design-patterns, strategy-pattern, state-pattern

I was reading through this [link](http://www.javabeat.net/state-pattern-design-patterns-in-javaj2ee/) about the state pattern. Is it looks like strategy pattern? What is the exact difference between these two patterns?

Comment: http://dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Strategy Design pattern and State Design pattern?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658192/what-is-the-difference-between-strategy-design-pattern-and-state-design-pattern)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The difference between State and Strategy is in the intent. With Strategy, the choice of algorithm is fairly stable. With State, a change in the state of the “context” object causes it to select from its “palette” of Strategy objects.

See http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state

Answer (score 2):

> Strategy Pattern is very similar to State Pattern. One of the
>   difference is that Context contains state as instance variable and
>   there can be multiple tasks whose implementation can be dependent on
>   the state whereas in strategy pattern strategy is passed as argument
>   to the method and context object doesn’t have any variable to store
>   it.

for more details see [Strategy design pattern in java example tutorial](http://www.journaldev.com/1754/strategy-design-pattern-in-java-example-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

I think one major difference is that:

-In **State** Pattern, we pass the context itself as a parameter to the method of the state concrete class we need to assign to the context and it do two things: at first it assigns itself to the sent context, Secondly, it performs its role.

-In **Strategy** Pattern, we pass the strategy to the context when we first create it, so it remains as it is for the whole program, unless we assign the same variable to a new context(pointer) in the memory using "new" and assign a new strategy to it, and after a while garbage collector would eliminate the old context with its assigned strategy.

More clearly, **Strategy** is fixed for one context and once assigned it cannot be changed, even the context does not have a strategy setter. But for **State**, many states can be assigned to the same context one after another, as the context has a setter for states.

I hope it is useful.

Answer (score 0):

In a State pattern,  usually an action of a state causes a change of state; in a strategy pattern, an action of a strategy does not causes a change of strategy. In other word, change of state lies in the state itself; change of strategy lies in external condition.

Answer (score 0):

From an excellent book ["Python Object-Oriented Programming: Build robust and maintainable object-oriented Python applications and libraries"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B094DJYLTV) by Steven Lott.

> The Strategy pattern is used to choose an algorithm at runtime;
> generally, only one of those algorithms is going to be chosen for a
> particular use case. The idea here is to provide an implementation
> choice at runtime, as late in the design process as possible. Strategy
> class definitions are rarely aware of other implementations; each
> Strategy generally stands alone.
>
> The State pattern, on the other hand, is designed to allow switching
> between different states dynamically, as some process evolves. In our
> example, the state changed as bytes were consumed and an evolving set
> of validity conditions satisfied. State definitions are generally
> defined as a group with an ability to switch among the various state
> objects.