# How to keep the interface segregation principle while using the state design pattern?

Tags: solid-principles, state-pattern, interface-segregation-principle

In a previous question on StackOverflow, I asked about preventing the `Context` class within a State design pattern from having too many responsibilities, and I received an answer on that (moving it all to the states) but now I wonder...

If I have an interface called `IState` and in that interface I list multiple methods that are applied by some of the states but not others (they simply return a message like, "Can't be done in state X") am I not breaking the interface segregation principle by forcing my states to depend on methods they do not implement?

I found an answer to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73521931/how-to-implement-state-design-pattern-without-violating-interface-segregation) on StackOverflow.
Now, I would argue that my question builds over this one because I want to also ask if I have this original `IState` with many methods:

```
interface IState {
  void OpenChargePort();
  void CloseChargePort();
  void PLayMusic();
  void StopMusic();
  void OpenWindow();
  void CloseWindow();
  void OpenTrunk();
  void CloseTrunk(); 
}
```

And I convert this to multiple smaller interfaces, following the Interface Segregation Principle:

```
interface IChagePort {
  void OpenChargePort();
  void CloseChargePort();
}
```

```
interface ITrunk {
  void OpenTrunk();
  void CloseTrunk(); 
}
```

Does this satisfy the State Design pattern?

Comment: Changing the interface from one state to another is the [difference between a State Machine and the State Design Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19859531/1371329).