# name of design pattern for below approach

Tags: design-patterns

I have open source code,my target was to add some functionality to this code without breaking the opensource structure.
 For example

```
class OpensourceClass{
       String getValue(){
         return "";
       }
   }
```

so I created a interface int class and a instance of that interface is introduced in opensource class

```
 class OpensourceClass{
       public static interface userImpl{
          String getValue();
       }

        private static userImpl obj;

      public static  void setUserImpl(userImpl ob){
          obj=ob;
      }
       String getValue(){
           if(userImpl)
              return userImpl.getValue();
             return "";
      }
    }
```

Just want to know which design pattern this..
Is it a strategy pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [Strategy (Policy)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) design pattern. Depending on the context it can also be called the [State](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) pattern. These two patterns are pretty similar, you can check this question for more details: [What is the difference between Strategy Design pattern and State Design pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658192/what-is-the-difference-between-strategy-design-pattern-and-state-design-pattern)

A more broader term is [Inversion of control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control). Using strategy design pattern is one of the basic techniques to implement inversion of control.

Also by trying to make your open-source class extensible you follow the [Open/closed principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle). As stated in [this](http://www.remondo.net/solid-principles-csharp-open-closed/) article the Strategy pattern is one of the ways to achieve Open/Closed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.   It is `Strategy` pattern.