# Chain of responsibility vs Finite State Machine - differences

Tags: design-patterns, state-machine, chain-of-responsibility

So as I am a bit of electrician and programmer I thought I knew FSM design pattern very well. It is:

- We have set of `Nodes`,
- Each `Node` knows, what to do, when program is in this node,
- Each `Node` `contains references to another chosen nodes`, and knows under what condition, should he proceed to the chosen one.
- On `event` or `after processing` a Node, `Node proceeds` to the next chosen Node

I thought, that it was quite clear to me. Although recently, when I was implementing a State Machine one person told me, that it is in fact a bit modified Chain of responsibility (not sure if he was correct) and , what I did/had was:

- Set of `Nodes` (which did not represented a linear or tree structure)
- Nodes had objects, that knew under which condition they should jump to which Node
- Each Node had it's **own context** of processing (some parts of contexts were shared between Nodes).

Unfortunatelly I am afraid, that due to legal issues I am not allowed to paste a class diagram here.

---

On the other hand we have got chain of responsibility, which I would (as I understand) define in a following way, that is:

- We have got some `ItemToProcess` Interface,
- We have got some `Node` Interface,
- Node has a reference to **only one** next Node,
- Each Node processes `ItemToProcess` and forwards processed one to the `nextNode`

So as far as I understand:

- We use `Chain Of Responsibility`, where we want **One** item to be processed (or at least tried to be processed) by **each** node
- Chain of responsibility represents **sequential and constant** execution of processes
- We use `StateMachine` to represent graphs
- We use `StateMachine` to perform computations, which order or kinds of computations **may vary** depending on some events.

I would like to ask you to confirm my understanding of those design patterns or tell me where I am making mistake in understanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your understanding is correct.

I would add that the Nodes in a FSM are different states. When you switch to a different node, **you change state**.  You may call the same state/node several consecutive times.

The chain of responsibility does not have different states. As you said, each node in the chain tries to process an object and if a node successfully processes the object, then usually the chain halts.

Common uses for chain of responsiblity are lookups for figuring out what Handler to use for a given input such as file types or extensions or finding items in a classpath or resource locator.  You can think of those types of operations as :

```
[Node 1]

"-Do you know what this is?"
-No
[Node 2]
"-Do you know what this is?"
-No
[Node 3]
"-Do you know what this is?"
-Yes!
```

done

Answer (score 6):

I'll complement the other answer by saying that design patterns also consider making software easily extendable.

*Chain of responsibility* has the advantage of being able to code new `ConcreteHandler` classes to extend your processing functionalities, without the `Client` class having to be modified.

[image: Class diagram of GoF Chain of Responsibility]

The code the builds the chain, however, must be modified to add the new handler as an object:

[image: Object diagram of GoF Chain of Responsibility]

*State* is not as flexible if you want to add new concrete states. The GoF book shows this diagram:

[image: Class diagram of GoF State]

What's not obvious (read more in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30424503/1168342)) is that `Handle()` events are coupled to another `ConcreteState` class (i.e., the next state). So, coding a new `ConcreteState` could require changes in some or all of the existing `ConcreteState` classes.

It's perhaps not as easy to add new states in the State pattern as it is to add new handlers in the Chain of Responsibility pattern.

Comment: Great, thank you. Could I ask what software did you use to draw those class diagrams?

Comment: @DawidPi Maybe you can ask your question on SO (how to put UML diagrams in a question or answer?) and I'll answer.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309523/how-one-should-add-uml-diagrams-to-the-question-or-answer